# Обработка данных из таблиц Excel

Tags: база-данных, excel

У меня имеется некоторое количество разнообразных excel-файлов. Один из них имеет следующую структуру (см. скриншот)

[image: Список должников]

Он представляет собой таблицу должников. Данные располагаются в столбцах:

- "Группа" (номер группы)
- "Физическое лицо" (ФИО студента)
- "Зачетная книжка" (номер зачетной книжки)
- "Дисциплина" (наименование дисциплины)
- "Вид контроля" (зачет, экзамен и т.д.)
- "Отметка" (незачет, неудовл и т.д.)
- "Период контроля" (номер семестра)
- "Тип ведомости" (основная, пересдача)
- "Индивидуальная ведомость" (да, нет)

Существуют какие-либо сервисы, программы для того, чтобы хранить подобную информацию в течение долгого времени, и на основании этих данных выполнять различные запросы, сравнения, анализ?

Таких файлов несколько. Их можно разбить на несколько групп. Каждый файл в группе имеет одинаковую структуру.

Проблема в том, что до этого идёт выгрузка этих документов в формат excel-таблиц, и необходимо именно из них получать различные выборки на основании запросов

Comment: есть же `Access` для баз данных и всяких разных запросов

Answer (score 0):

Встречал организацию подобных данных в [Qlikview](https://www.qlik.com/ru-ru). Таблицы можно загружать по-отдельности, а после для целей анализа объединить в одну общую (вообще говоря, Клик автоматически их объединит, если набор полей одинаковый).

Далее на усмотрение можно сделать сводные таблицы, диаграммы, дашборды

Сам по себе Клик предназначен для удобства аналитики и сравнения, а не для хранения данных, но имеет возможность схоронить данные в более экономный формат .qvd

Слышал и хорошие отзывы и не очень, но в любом случае стоит познакомиться с инструментом [например тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/218737/)